# 2 male pups from different litters

Tags: dogs, pet-selection, adoption

We want to adopt two male pups that come from different homes and different litters  would this work? One is spayed not sure about the other one. Please advise!

Answer (score 2):

Sure dogs get a along all the time. They go to the park and play with dogs from other homes.  If one or both are aggressive that is a problem that is not different home or different litter thing.

There is a bounty on how to know if two dogs will get along. 
The best way to determine if two dogs will get along is to introduce them. 
If they have issues they will typically let you know right away.

Aggressive dogs tends to not get along but with the right trainer they do. 
If the human is the alpha then things work.

An aggressive/dominant dog with a submissive can work.  Will the submissive enjoy the relationship?   Since the dog can't talk I don't really know.  From what I can tell a submissive would rather just have an attentive owner.

If you are not experienced with dogs then one dog may be better. You need to establish yourself as the alpha and train the dog. With two or more dogs they will focus on each other.  For training just isolate the dogs and train one at a time.  A typical training session is 20 minutes so not a big time commitment.

That said if you can establish as the alpha and train two or more dogs then as a dog owner it becomes easier.  The dogs can entertain each other and you don't have to give the dogs as much time.

You can't really go by breed or even litter as it varies.  There is the story of the [dog and elephant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Au2cQGaQBc).

Answer (score 1):

Many people would say adopting two puppies at the same time regardless of if they are from the same liter or not is a bad idea.  I'm including a few of the 6 main points from this article that state why it's a bad idea(http://www.whole-dog-journal.com/issues/13_1/features/Problems-Adopting-Two-Puppies-At-Once_16190-1.html).

> Two-pup rationale #1: “I want to get two puppies so they will have
>   someone to play with while I’m gone all day at work.”
>
> It’s a good thing to recognize that your pup could use companionship
>   during the day. However, if you think one puppy can get into trouble
>   when you’re not there, just think what kinds of mischief two pups can
>   cook up when left to their own devices. Better solutions might
>   include:
>
> • Adopt your new pup at a time when someone in your family can take a
>   week (or several) off work to stay home and help the puppy adjust
>   gradually to being left alone. A couple of weeks vacation time? Kids
>   home for the summer? Just be sure to use the time wisely, so your pup
>   can learn to happily accept being alone when it’s time to go back to
>   work or school.
>
> • Find a friend, neighbor, or relative who is home much of the time
>   and who is willing to provide daycare for your pup - and experience
>   the joys of having a puppy to play with during the day, without the
>   long-term responsibilities and costs of having a dog for 15-plus
>   years.
>
> • Ask your vet if she has another client with a similar-age puppy, and
>   see if the two of you can mingle your pups at one of your
>   puppy-proofed homes for puppy daycare, and send the second baby dog
>   back home after work. Note the emphasis on “puppy-proofed.” Two pups
>   can still get into a heap of trouble, even if one of them isn’t yours.
>
> Two-pup rationale #2: I have two children and they each want their own
>   puppy.
>
> What a sweet idea. Just say no. Since when do the kids get to make the
>   rules? Seriously, most families have enough trouble getting their kids
>   to fulfill their promise to feed, walk, and clean up after one family
>   dog. Mom ends up doing most of it anyway. So now Mom gets to do
>   double-puppy-duty? If there’s a compelling reason for them each to
>   have a dog, consider adopting one puppy now, and an adult dog from a
>   shelter or rescue group. Even then, I’d adopt one first and give her
>   at least a month to settle in, if not longer, before adopting the
>   second.
>
> Two-pup rationale #3: We want to have two dogs eventually anyway, so
>   we might as well get them at the same time so they can grow up
>   together as best friends.
>
> Well, that’s what you might well get! When you raise two puppies
>   together they usually do grow up to be inseparable best friends, often
>   to the detriment of the dog-human relationship. Inevitably they spend
>   far more time together than they do individually with you, with a
>   likely result that they become very tightly bonded to each other and
>   you are only secondary in their lives. Many owners of
>   adopted-at-the-same-time puppies ultimately find themselves
>   disappointed in their relationships with their dogs, even when they
>   are committed to keeping them for life.
>
> This super-bonding also causes tremendous stress (and stress-related
>   behavior problems) on those occasions when the dogs do have to be
>   separated - and sooner or later, something will come up that requires
>   them to be separated: one goes to training class and the other
>   doesn’t, you want to walk one but not both, or a health-related
>   problem requires one to be hospitalized or otherwise kept separate.
>
> Of course you want your dogs to get along. But you probably don’t want
>   them to get along so well with each other that they hardly take notice
>   of the human members of the family – a common result of raising canine
>   siblings together.
>
> Two-pup rationale #4: A second puppy will play with the first and keep
>   her occupied when I’m too busy to spend time with her.
>
> Nice thought, but here’s a heads-up. If you’re too busy to give one
>   puppy the time she needs, you’re definitely too busy for two puppies!
>
> There are great interactive dog toys on the market that can help
>   occupy your pup when you can’t play with her - and don’t think that
>   either another puppy or a pen full of toys can substitute for social
>   time with you. Puppies do take time, and it’s important you give that
>   some serious thought before adding a baby dog to the family. It’s fine
>   to give her playmate-time via arranged play dates with a friend’s
>   healthy and compatible puppy, but don’t think adopting a second pup is
>   an acceptable substitute for your own interaction with your puppy.
>
> Two-pup rationale #5: If we adopt a second puppy, that’s one fewer
>   that might be euthanized.
>
> I won’t argue with this, except to say that in many shelters around
>   the country today, puppies aren’t the problem. Of course there are
>   exceptions, but I’d say the majority of shelters in the United States
>   now have no problems placing most if not all the puppies they get.
>   It’s the adult dogs who are most likely to die because of
>   homelessness. If you really want to save a life, adopt a grown-up dog
>   instead of a puppy, or at least adopt your puppy now, and come back
>   for an adult dog in a few months.
>
> Two-pup rationale #6: The breeder we are buying our puppy from thinks
>   it’s best if we take two.
>
> If you’re buying from a breeder who encourages you to purchase two
>   puppies at once, run away fast. A truly responsible breeder will, in
>   most cases, refuse to sell two puppies to one home, except on the rare
>   occasion that a prospective buyer can prove she has the skill,
>   knowledge, time, ability, and monetary resources to provide an
>   excellent environment for two pups at once. Someone who tries to push
>   two puppies on a buyer isn’t a very responsible breeder, and isn’t
>   doing her puppies, or the new owner, any favors.

Answer (score -1):

**Only if they are both spayed**. Having two male dogs, one fixed and the other not, is a bad idea and will create aggression.